# Dependency Injection and Java packages

Tags: java, dependency-injection, package

I'm doing a project that has a couple of packages. All my classes are implemented according to Dependency Injection ideias.

Now, there will be some place, in my application, that'll have the responsability of instantiating all the objects (actually I'm using an IoC Container for that, but that shouldn't matter) -- the so called Composition Root.

Now, the problem lies in the fact that, at least to my understanding, the composition root will have to know all the classes that'll be used of the system. That is, all the classes will have to be marked as public.

I could define for each package a Package Composition Root and then call each one of them from the system's composition Root but that doesn't seem that great of an idea.

In C#, for example, the situation is not so grave as there is not the package-protected access modifier -- there's internal (accessible for all the elements of the current assembly), instead.

How do you guys generally handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most containers get around access restrictions by using reflection. However this is just a hack to make you feel like you have some protection when actually relfection allows you to ignore the access modifiers.

IMHO, if you are accessing a class in another package you should be clear about this and give it an appropriate access modifier.

Comment: The thing is, wouldn't I be using DI, I could keep all those "periferical" package-protected classes...package protected.

Comment: If you use OSGi, you can define this sort of thing in more detail. A module has to explicity export the packages which are available.  I would question what you really gain by being more qualified about you access modifiers.

Comment: You can leave them package private or even private if you wish and access them via reflection.  However you are lively to find it simpler and less error prone to make the compoents public and use them directly.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds to me like the situation is the same in C#.  If the bean factory is outside of a package, and the developer makes a class internal, does that not deny access to the bean factory?

I make the classes public and don't worry so much about it.

The interfaces that clients should be using are public by definition.  Since they don't instantiate or use the implementations directly, there's little fear of giving them public access.

An alternative might be to create a factory method and make it available to the bean factory.  Let it choose which implementation to provide for a given implementation using the public factory.

Comment: in C# the classes are internal. any other class from the same assembly (read, .dll) can use them. but yes, if you are trying to build up a multi assembly project, the issue remains the same.

Comment: But, like I said, the bean factory is unlikely to be part of the same assembly.  Java doesn't suffer from the problem if the bean factory was part of the package.  It's the same problem.  It's disingenuous to imply (incorrectly) that .NET performs some magic to remain immune.

Comment: Who said .NET does some magic? I said (and stand correct) that internal's access modifier is way more useful for this case than package-protected.

Comment: @devoured, I think you are missing that most of the answers here are arguing that this "problem" of having public classes is not a true problem worth worrying about, regardless of whether modifiers in C# make it easier or not.

Answer (score 3):

> Now, the problem lies in the fact that, at least to my understanding, the composition root will have to know all the classes that'll be used of the system. That is, all the classes will have to be marked as public.
>   ...
>   How do you guys generally handle this?

By marking all of the classes as `public`. This isn't really seen as a problem in the Java world.

Comment: +1: Only the class access in other packages need to be public. Unless every class can be a component, perhaps this isn't required.

Comment: Having all classes public doesn't seem to me as the greatest of the ideas (that is, if they don't have to be). Do you mark all your methods, all your fields as public?

Comment: No, the only methods I make public are those that implement an interface, or are simple getter/setter methods in POJOs. I am not a believer that having `public` classes is a problem - I am not worried about another developer on my project maliciously using my code for something other than it is intended. There are other ways of enforcing separation of concerns, modularity, layering, etc., than with access modifiers. Contrast this with a language like Python where there are no access modifiers whatsoever - just developers that document which methods are for public consumption and which are not.

Comment: Not all methods; almost no fields.  That's not what matt b. said.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I think is very important to still talk about that. While other guys try to say there is no problem with making classes of packages public to be accessible for composition, I disagree completely. The most import feature of a package is to hide details from the others using access modifiers. You can argue about the details word and say the main class of a package that provides its main features is not details of the package. I will answer when you use polymorphic interfaces to isolate your package from outside world, that main class is also part of details. Restricting access to that main class is useful when you want to protect your software architecture from being violated by the other developers in you team by the aid of language features at compile time. If you do not have such a feature in Python, I feel sorry for you but it doesn't mean there is no need to use such a great feature in Java, C#, etc.

Suppose you have a package that communicate with the outside world using a polymorphic interface and all of its internal types are access-restricted. So how the main class that implements that interface can be initialized in the composition phase while composition operation is happening out of all packages? This is the main question.

As Devoured also mentioned himself, there is no way except defining a public composer in each package that instantiates and composes all internal types and finally returns an object of the type of the polymorphic interface that isolates this module from the outside world.